# Mysql Query Not Working giving duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table tblclients and mod_autorenewdomain
tblclients columns which I required:

1. id
2. firstname
3. lastname

mod_autorenewdomain columns:

1. id
2. userid
3. autorenew
4. days

I have inserted in mod_autorenewel table, next I want to show the clients which are not added in mod_autorenewel table
The query I am trying is not working

```
Select  c.id,c.firstname,c.lastname from tblclients as c  join mod_autorenewdomain as m ON c.id!=m.userid ORDER BY c.id ASC
```

It is showing the result as follows:

```
id  firstname   lastname    
12  Adil        Mukarram
13  M. Mahad    Ashraf
14  Zeeshan     Mushtaq
14  Zeeshan     Mushtaq
15  Muhammad    Suhaib
15  Muhammad    Suhaib
```

Firstly I have added with id 12 and 13 in mod_autorenewdomain table so these records does not show but they are displaying
Secondly the other records are repeating Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `left join` to find non-matching records:

```
Select  c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname
from tblclients c left join
     mod_autorenewdomain m 
     on c.id = m.userid
where m.userid is null
order by c.id ASC;
```

That is, use the `FROM` clause to look for matches.  Then use the `WHERE` clause to find the records that do not match.

Comment: Can u tell me for the other case means matching case query as well ?

Comment: You were faster, again :-)

Comment: @Koshinae I cannot understand his last line that's why I said otherwise it's simple for matching case

Comment: Oh, I meant to say that to Gordon. Sorry for the misunderstanding :)

Comment: @zeeshanMushtaq . . . I'll try again.  The `left join` finds all rows that match in `m` but it also keeps all rows in `c` that have no match.  The `where` clause gets only these rows.